# How can I ensure or force a message I'm composing to go via SMS on my iPhone 6 in iOS 12?

Tags: iphone, ios, messages

In answers to [When does Messages message via iMessage vs. SMS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/375860/143729) I learned that if a contact is set up such that they have received iMessages from me, there still may be a way to force a new message I'm composing to go via SMS. I might want to do this if I suspect they are not connected to the internet but I need them to receive the current message quickly.

**Question:** How can I ensure or force a message I'm composing to go via SMS on my iPhone 6 in iOS 12?

- Comments from 2016 (but no answers) to [Force outgoing SMS instead of iMessage from an iPhone 6S+ to a specific contact who uses iPhone/iMessage?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/260035/143729) seem to say this can't be done, but that was three years ago.
- [This answer from 2014](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/155837/143729) points to answers about how to modify the receiving phone's situation. Here I'm asking about forcing SMS on a single, current message on the sender's phone.

Comment: I'm just looking for a way to do this, not an explanation why I shouldn't want to, thanks!

Comment: Even with the original question not having an answer this still is a duplicate.

Comment: @nohillside since mine is more specific and up to date, why not close that one instead?

Comment: It doesn‘t really matter. The other Q already has some comments indicating that it can‘t be done. AFAIK this is still the case but am curios whether Nimesh can provide a solution.

Comment: @nohillside okay I'll keep an eye on that (I saw your comment to Nimesh). The way iOS evolves, three year old information, and *in comments* no less may not really apply today.

Comment: I answered you on the main thread - what I write there applies to iOS 12 and all devices.

Comment: I've voted to re-open; the 2nd half of [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/375864/143729) exactly answers this question and in a much better way than answers to the current dupe do.