# Stop my iPhone from receiving screen shots and other images sent via SMS?

Tags: ios, graphics, sms

I like to use SMS text messages and not iMessage, and only for text as indicated in the linked questions below.

Today I got a screenshot of a LINE message in an SMS text message and I certainly do not want to receive content in LINE messages as SMS text messages, nor any images at all.

Is there anything I can do to stop my iPhone from receiving screen shots and other images to me via SMS?

---

- [How can I ensure or force a message I'm composing to go via SMS on my iPhone 6 in iOS 12?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/375873/143729)
- [When does Messages message via iMessage vs. SMS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/375860/143729)

Comment: I don't believe this is possible. You'd almost have to check with your cell phone carrier to see if they would allow SMS but block MMS, and I find it hard to believe that any of them would be able to do that, even if they wanted to.

Comment: Do you have "MMS Messaging" enabled or disabled in your Settings app in the Messages settings?

Comment: @Nic well look at that! [before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BKUJ.jpg) and [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0720.jpg). I'll try to do an experiment to see if it stops it. Feel free to write up an answer in the mean time, I would guess that this is exactly what I needed :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try disabling "MMS Messaging" in your Settings app in the Messages settings.

[image]

Comment: Yes I do! I had a substantial software upgrade recently and I'm still discovering settings. I've turned it off now and I'll try to test this again in the next few days. *Thanks!*