# How to turn off fireworks on my phone after texting "Happy New Year" and any future shenanigans?

Tags: ios, sms

Today is 14-Feb-2021 and I SMS texted "Happy New Year" to someone since it is the Lunar New Year holiday season.

After sending the text message my phone displayed a few second animation of a fireworks display.

**Question:** How can I turn off this kind of annoying animation shenanigans?

I've already done this: [Stop my iPhone from receiving screen shots and other images sent via SMS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/383801/143729)

My personal preference is to have a phone that simply does what it's told. Thank you in advance for not telling me that I should "think different"!

---

messaging myself in order to reproduce the problem:

[image]

Comment: https://www.payetteforward.com/turn-off-messages-effects-iphone-heres-fix/

Answer (score 5):

Go to Settings and then tap on Accessibility. in Accessibility go to Motion. The new pane that opens has a switch to turn off "Auto-Play Message Effects". Turn this off and that should solve your problem.

Comment: Doesn't this also require turning on "Reduce Motion"? That will have many side effects. :(

Comment: @Wowfunhappy     Not on my iphone 11 running 14.4.  I have Reduce Motion turned off and I can turn the Auto-play message effects on or off.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! When I go to Settings > General > Accessibility I see the Reduce Motion control but nothing called just "Motion" and searching for "motion" only shows the Reduce Motion option. iPhone 6 with 12.4.5 https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PLEc.jpg