# Messages.app / iMessage hijacking text messages

Tags: macos, ios, messages

Text messages to my number are received either by my phone or by Messages.app (iMessage), but not both. If I leave my computer on then I will inexplicably not receive texts on my phone (until the computer goes to sleep, I suppose).

How do I configure my devices so that Messages would contain the same information as my iPhone?

OS X 10.10.1, iOS 7.1.2, iPhone 5s, MacBook Pro 2009

Comment: You don't receive them at all on iPhone, or they just appear in the conversation history but not as new messages? Also I would strongly recommend upgrading to iOS 8 as it would play better with Yosemite.

Comment: Make sure you have both set to be able to contact you at, at least, your phone number & your iCloud 'main' email address.

Comment: Upgrade your phone!

Comment: also see [How to tell Messages "I'm not at home"?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/153492/how-to-tell-messages-im-not-at-home)

Answer (score 1):

I think it is s matter of having wifi on at your Mac. Once it goes to sleep, wifi is off and you receive iMessages on your phone. Right now, the only thing I found that worked is either have your data on at all times on your phone or make sure your Mac is turned of when you leave.