# Missing iOS iMessage showing in OSX Messages

Tags: macos, ios, data-synchronization, messages

This is the second time this has happened to me in the past couple of days so it starts to bother me: somebody sends me an iMessage, that I never get on my iPhone (4S iOS 8.2) but I do get on my Macbook's (OS 10.10.2 Yosemite) Messages application (v8.0). Even days later the messages are not appearing on my iPhone.

Do you have any idea why this is happening and how I could manually force a synchronization?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can happen if your phone is outside good reception area for iMessage - carrier signal dropped to GPRS/Edge etc.

The Mac picks it up, the system considers it delivered.
There is no further attempt to send it to your phone.

It used to happen to me a lot when I was working in a low-reception area.

It won't re-synchronise.

See [How to tell Messages "I'm not at home"?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/153492/how-to-tell-messages-im-not-at-home) for a similar experience.

It doesn't happen if your phone is set to airplane mode, or off altogether. For some reason, that will trigger a delivery of missed messages when you switch back on again.

[All of this may be mobile-operator influenced - I've never been able to figure that part out - whether it happens to everyone or just certain carriers.]

Comment: This answer does not pan. Yesterday I sent messages from my iPhone (iOS 8.4.1) which was riding with me down the highway and my Mac Book (Yosemite 10.10.5) was asleep in the briefcase in the back seat (no WiFi to be seem) and it didn't come out till after 9:00 PM. The two messages were sent at 6:36 AM from my home where the WiFi is great the replies were at 11:40 AM. I never have seen it on my iPhone but it is on the Mac Book that was sleeping in the back seat on I-39 no where near a WiFi hot spot. I'm beginning to think that iCloud knows me in three places (iMessage (Mac and iOS) and MSG my p