# Messages.app not downloading messages send/received on iPhone

Tags: macos, messages

I've been recently trying to fix an issues with Messages.app. My iPhone sends/receives all of the messages fine, on my Mac Messages.app will display these messages if the Mac is switched on.

However, if I leave my Mac off then the messages do not appear in Messages.app which is incredibly frustrating.

I have tried signing in and out on both devices, but nothing changes. Forwarded SMS is also having this issue.

I'm currently running OSX 10.10.3 and iOS 8.3 12F70

Comment: Try deactivating iMessage on Mac, leaving it off for about 15 to 30 minutes, then reactivating it.

Comment: @tubedogg Tried that and it seemed to assume it was a new machine, but nope this didn't fix it :(

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it will even attempt to distribute messages to all possible destinations once one has definitely received it.

I had a similar issue last year when my phone would be out of range for iMessage for most of the day, but my Mac at home was happily picking them up - I didn't see any of them til I got home :(

See [How to tell Messages "I'm not at home"?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/153492/how-to-tell-messages-im-not-at-home) which is similar, but the opposite way round.
None of the proposed solutions worked for me at the time - perhaps would be different now I'm on Yosemite, but I won't get chance to test unless I get the same job this summer, in the same out-of-range location.

Comment: It's supposed to deliver a message to all registered devices. Each time a message is sent to you, it's actually _n_ messages being sent, where _n_ is the number of registered devices, because it is encrypted with each public key that you have (one per device that you use). Obviously it's glitchy sometimes, but it is _not_ supposed to stop after the first device. One way I know this is when I have Messages closed (not running at all) on Mac, and then open it, and it downloads messages that I deleted on iPhone 3 days ago.

Comment: I can only speak through experience - I lost a lot of work last summer, because of that glitch. I need to reply within minutes on the job offers I get; by the time I get back home is way too late :(

Comment: Thing is that it was working perfectly before, it would just download the messages (although slowly) whenever I woke my Mac back up. Now, the only complete record of iMessages is on my iPhone as it's constantly connected.